# How to count row values from file?

Tags: java, text-files

i am trying to read the txt file and add up row values i.e i am passing the parameters to java code. it should print the line numbers of added values

i am passing filename and int value to java program.

for ex: `read.txt` contains

```
2
2
3
4
4
6
7
7
8
8
9
0
```

now i am passing parameter as 5, so it should add up the rows and print the line number and it should print the line number if the sum >= 5

for ex 
`2+2+3 = 7 is > 5`
because the last number added up is 3 and it is in line number 3
so it should print line number 3

`4+4 = 8 is > 5`
so it should print line number 3

`6 is > 5` 
so it should print line number 6
because its in line number 6

and so on..
how can i do this?

here is what i have tried

code:

```
import java.io.*;

class CountR
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        setForSum("read.txt",3);
    }

    public static void setForSum(String filename,int param2)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filename);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;
            int i = 0;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
            {
                i++;
                if(param2 == Integer.parseInt(strLine))
                { 
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your code work - if not what does it do that is wrong?

Comment: This code works, but now it is printing only the line number where the given number lies...
ie. given number is 3 and it is showing the line number 3 because it lies in line number 3.

Answer (score 1):

**First thing** I've noticed, is this `if statement` is only going to work if you land on your specified number, exactly.

```
 if(param2 == Integer.parseInt(strLine))
 { 
      System.out.println(i);
 }
```

Should be:

```
 if(param2 >= Integer.parseInt(strLine))
 { 
      System.out.println(i);
 }
```

**Secondly**, you're not totalling up the values, are you? You're just reading each value, so declare some value outside of the loop:

```
int currentTotal = 0;
```

then in the loop:

```
currentTotal += Integer.valueOf(strLine);
```

THEN use `currentTotal` in your statement:

```
if(currentTotal >= Integer.parseInt(strLine))
{ 
  System.out.println("Line Number " + i);
}
```

And as `Heuster` mentioned, make sure you're resetting `currentTotal` back to 0 inside your if statement!

Comment: And reset `currentTotal` in your `if` :)

Comment: Added a bit on the end of the question :)